Can't transmit the computer's audio (the one that goes to the speakers)
main.py
from flask import Flask,Response,render_template
import soundcard as sc

app=Flask(__name__,template_folder="template")

CHANNELS=2
RATE=44100
CHUNK=1024
RECORD_SECONDS=5


def genHeader(sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels):
    datasize = 2000*10**6
    o = bytes("RIFF",'ascii')                                            
    o += (datasize + 36).to_bytes(4,'little')                            
    o += bytes("WAVE",'ascii')                                              
    o += bytes("fmt ",'ascii')                                              
    o += (16).to_bytes(4,'little')                 
    o += (1).to_bytes(2,'little')   
    o += (channels).to_bytes(2,'little')          
    o += (sampleRate).to_bytes(4,'little')                                  
    o += (sampleRate * channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(4,'little')  
    o += (channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(2,'little')               
    o += (bitsPerSample).to_bytes(2,'little')                               
    o += bytes("data",'ascii')                                              
    o += (datasize).to_bytes(4,'little')                                   
    return o



def Sound():
    bitspersample=16
    wav_hader=genHeader(RATE,bitspersample,2)
    first_run=True
    with sc.get_microphone(id=str(sc.default_speaker().name), include_loopback=True).recorder(samplerate=RATE) as mic:
        
        while True:
            if first_run:
                data=wav_hader+mic.record(numframes=RATE).tobytes()
                first_run=False
            else:
                data=mic.record(numframes=RATE).tobytes()
            yield(data)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("Audio.html")

@app.route("/audio")
def audio():
    return Response(Sound())

app.run(host="127.0.0.1",port=5454,threaded=True)


Audio.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="{{ url_for('audio') }}" type="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm" >
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>

You tried to take a PyAudio code (that worked) that records from the computer's microphone and sends it live to Audio.html, and I tried unsuccessfully to combine it with another code that records the sound from the computer system, so that the python will broadcast live to Audio.html the sound of the computer system
